# Zend Framework has problems with CamelCase Controller Names?

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, routes, zend-route, camelcasing

I have a Zend Framework application I've been working on my local machine, I've deploying it to a server but having .htaccess issues because **some but not all routes fail with a "*Page Not Found*"**. Very weird that I can't access some controllers.

My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteBase /~user/path/to/app/public/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This error does not occur on the local machine, only on the server. The only thing I can see that is common to the controllers that have a "*Page Not Found*" error on the server is that the Controller names are camel case.

Controllers that work: CustomerController, InvoiceController, StockController. Controllers that fail: SuppliersStockController, StockTypesController.

If I try to do something like 'www.route/to/app/stock-types/' or '/stock.types/' I get an "*Application Error*".

Comment: are you sure that the views are in place and named correctly?

Comment: @Songo - Yep, as I said the whole application works on my local machine. There's no difference between my machine and the server other than the .htaccess which is just the line for the RewriteBase.

Comment: presuming that there is a method StockTypesController::indexAction(), does a call to /stock-types/index also fail? [Not suggesting that the app require this; just for diagnostic purposes].

Comment: Another thought: Windows on local dev machine with *nix on the production side often accounts for different behavior, due to *nix filesystem case-sensitivity.

Comment: @DavidWeinraub Correct, there is an indexAction() and calls to /stock-types/index also fails with "Application Error" (/stocktypes/index fails with "Page Not Found"). Should have said in original post, local machine is a Mac running MAMP, server is CentOS.

Comment: OK, I've partially fixed the problem. By adding SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development to the .htaccess I got a better error description. Zend is looking for a view script called "stock-types" for the StockTypeController. Renaming fixes the problem, but that doesn't explain the difference in behaviour between my local machine and the server :(

Comment: what versions of PHP and ZF are on your dev machine and your server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are seeing the effect of a case sensitive file system.

When you go to `/stocktypes/index`, ZF will look for `StocktypesController.php` and succeed on case insensitive systems like Mac OS X and Windows. On Linux however, it will fail.

If you go to `/stock-types/index`, then ZF will look for `StockTypesController.php` and will find it on Linux.

If ZF finds a CamelCased controller name, then it will look for a view folder with a hyphen.

Comment: I ran into the same issue - thanks for the hint with the hyphen!